# More Efficient Way To Search On-Demand

Tags: c#, performance, event-handling, wpf, xaml

I need better logic that would allow this search to perform quicker and more efficiently.

In XAML, I have a `DataGrid` and a `TextBox`.  Both need to be present.

I'd prefer that as the user types in the `TextBox`, the `Grid` is filtered by one or more columns. Not that the user needs to click a "Submit" button (unless this is the only way).

My current logic takes many seconds to complete, likely because of the binding/rebinding of the UI.

Here is my logic:

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) {
    var textBox = sender as TextBox;
    _filteredView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MainGrid.DataContext);
    _filteredView.Filter = x => ((QueueData)x).ImageCode.Contains(textBox.Text) || ((QueueData)x).Product.Contains(textBox.Text);

    MainGrid.DataContext = ((System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView)_filteredView).SourceCollection;
}
```

Below is my xaml - txtSearch is the `TextBox`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Wip.Presentation.ManagerWindow"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             TextElement.FontWeight="Medium"
             TextElement.FontSize="14"
             TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Ideal" 
             TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Auto"
             TextElement.Foreground="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignBody}"
             Background="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignPaper}"
             FontFamily="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFont}"
             mc:Ignorable="d" Height="auto" Width="auto">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="LeftCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                              VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" PreviewMouseWheel="ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel">
        <Grid Background="Transparent" FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=txtSearch}">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <!-- SEARCH -->
            <Label HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0" Name="lblSearch" Height="30" Width="150" Margin="10,0,0,0" >SEARCH (F5 to clear)</Label>
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0" Name="txtSearch" Height="30" Width="200" Margin="160,0,0,0" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" CharacterCasing="Upper"/>

            <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Name="MainGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
              Sorting="MainGrid_Sorting"
              SelectionChanged="MainGrid_SelectionChanged"
              MouseDoubleClick="MainGrid_MouseDoubleClick"
              ColumnWidth="Auto"
              AlternationCount="2"
              AlternatingRowBackground="DimGray"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              AreRowDetailsFrozen="True" Margin="0,0,0,0">

                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="CMP" Width="50" Binding="{Binding Company, Mode=OneWay}" CellStyle="{StaticResource LeftCellStyle}"  SortMemberPath="(Company)" IsReadOnly="True">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF666666" />
                                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>

                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="DIV" Width="50"  Binding="{Binding Division, Mode=OneWay}" CellStyle="{StaticResource LeftCellStyle}" SortMemberPath="(Division)" IsReadOnly="True">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF666666" />
                                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>

                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="CUS" Width="75" Binding="{Binding CustomerNumber, Mode=OneWay}" CellStyle="{StaticResource LeftCellStyle}" SortMemberPath="(CustomerNumber)" IsReadOnly="True">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF666666" />
                                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>

                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="FORMAT" Width="75" Binding="{Binding ImageCode, Mode=OneWay}" CellStyle="{StaticResource LeftCellStyle}" SortMemberPath="(ImageCode)" IsReadOnly="True">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF666666" />
                                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>

                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="SEQ" Width="50" Binding="{Binding Sequence, Mode=OneWay}" CellStyle="{StaticResource LeftCellStyle}" SortMemberPath="(Sequence)" IsReadOnly="True">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF666666" />
                                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>

                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ORDER #" Width="75"  Binding="{Binding OrderNumber, Mode=OneWay}" CellStyle="{StaticResource LeftCellStyle}" SortMemberPath="(OrderNumber)" IsReadOnly="True">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF666666" />
                                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>

                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="LOGO" Width="225" Binding="{Binding Logo, Mode=OneWay}" CellStyle="{StaticResource LeftCellStyle}" SortMemberPath="(Logo)" IsReadOnly="True">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF666666" />
                                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>

                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Hold Code" Width="100" Binding="{Binding HoldCode, Mode=OneWay}" CellStyle="{StaticResource LeftCellStyle}" SortMemberPath="(HoldCode)" IsReadOnly="True">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF666666" />
                                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>

                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Order Type" Width="85" Binding="{Binding Dhotp, Mode=OneWay}" CellStyle="{StaticResource LeftCellStyle}" SortMemberPath="(Dhotp)" IsReadOnly="True">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF666666" />
                                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>

                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Comments" Width="175" Binding="{Binding Comments, Mode=OneWay}" CellStyle="{StaticResource LeftCellStyle}" SortMemberPath="(Comments)" IsReadOnly="True">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF666666" />
                                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>

                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="IMPORT DATE" Width="160" Binding="{Binding ImportDate, Mode=OneWay}" CellStyle="{StaticResource LeftCellStyle}" SortMemberPath="(ImportDate)" IsReadOnly="True">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF666666" />
                                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>

                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="PRODUCT" Width="110" Binding="{Binding Product, Mode=OneWay}" CellStyle="{StaticResource LeftCellStyle}" SortMemberPath="(Product)" IsReadOnly="True">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF666666" />
                                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>

                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="WORKCNTR" Width="110" Binding="{Binding Product, Mode=OneWay}" CellStyle="{StaticResource LeftCellStyle}" SortMemberPath="(WorkCenter)" IsReadOnly="True">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF666666" />
                                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>

                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="PROCESS TYPE" Width="100"  Binding="{Binding ProcessType, Mode=OneWay}" CellStyle="{StaticResource LeftCellStyle}" SortMemberPath="(ProcessType)" IsReadOnly="True">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF666666" />
                                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>

                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="PIM EMB JOB" Width="105"  Binding="{Binding PimEmbJobDisplay, Mode=OneWay}" CellStyle="{StaticResource LeftCellStyle}" SortMemberPath="(PimEmbJob)" IsReadOnly="True">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF666666" />
                                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>

                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dgcThreadColor" Header="THREAD COLOR" Width="105"  Binding="{Binding Ink, Mode=OneWay}" CellStyle="{StaticResource LeftCellStyle}" SortMemberPath="(Ink)" IsReadOnly="True">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF666666" />
                                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>

                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dgcStitchCnt" Header="STITCH CNT" Width="105"  Binding="{Binding StitchCount, Mode=OneWay}" CellStyle="{StaticResource LeftCellStyle}" SortMemberPath="(StitchCount)" IsReadOnly="True">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF666666" />
                                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>

                    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dgcPieces" Header="PIECES" Width="105"  Binding="{Binding Pieces, Mode=OneWay}" CellStyle="{StaticResource LeftCellStyle}" SortMemberPath="(Pieces)" IsReadOnly="True">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF666666" />
                                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>

                </DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Mark SLC" Name="mnuMarkSLC" Click="mnuMarkSLC_Click">

                        </MenuItem>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</UserControl>
```

Below is QueueData.cs:

```
using System;

namespace Wip.ViewModels {
    public class QueueData {
        #region Public Properties
        public string Company { get; set; }
        public string Division { get; set; }
        public string CustomerNumber { get; set; }
        public string ImageCode { get; set; }
        public int Sequence { get; set; }
        public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
        public string Logo { get; set; }
        public int LineNumber { get; set; }
        public string HoldCode { get; set; }
        public string Dhotp { get; set; }
        public string Comments { get; set; }
        public string WorkCenter { get; set; }

        public DateTime ImportDate { get; set; }

        // Due Date

        public string Product { get; set; }

        // Ink

        public int ProcessType { get; set; }
        public bool ProductionEdit { get; set; }
        public bool PimEmbJob { get; set; }
        public string PimEmbJobDisplay { get { return (PimEmbJob == true ? "Yes" : "No"); } }
        public string Ink { get; set; }
        public int StitchCount { get; set; }
        public int Pieces { get; set; }
        // Work Center
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you need to rebind the data context when using CollectionViewSource.Filter?

Comment: I am not sure at all.  I hacked through the code I found on StackExchange. Are you suggesting `filteredView` is bound implicitly?

Comment: here's a tutorial: you need to bind to the source collection and use the collectionview to filter and call refresh. but you should never rebind the data context: https://grantwinney.com/using-a-textbox-and-collectionviewsource-to-filter-a-listview-in-wpf/ This tutorial is better than my answer was :)

Comment: My TextChanged now has

`CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MainGrid.DataContext).Filter = x => ((QueueData)x).ImageCode.Contains(textBox.Text) || ((QueueData)x).Product.Contains(textBox.Text);`

It still lags.  Is that to be expected?

Comment: Try the pattern from tutorial, it sets the Filter once, and refreshes on text changed.

Comment: I've tried the pattern and find it takes 300-500ms for the first letter in the search and halfs each letter afterwards, for example: 250ms for the second letter, 20-80 for the third - starting with ~108 records. Not sure where the bottleneck is.

Comment: Perhaps you should put a Delay on the Binding

Answer (score 2):

I would handle the data source a little different than you:

In your code behind for the control, you can initialize in the following way:

```
public ManagerWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  _viewSource = new CollectionViewSource();
  _viewSource.Source = InitializeView();
  _viewSource.Filter += ViewSource_Filter;
  MainGrid.ItemsSource = _viewSource.View;
}

private void ViewSource_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
  string text = txtSearch.Text;
  QueueData data = e.Item as QueueData;
  e.Accepted = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text) || (data != null && (data.ImageCode.Contains(text) || data.Product.Contains(text)));
}

CollectionViewSource _viewSource;
```

Where `InitializeView()` is a method defined by you, that must return a collection (`List<QueueData>`) or something like that. But as you probably know it can be set in many other ways.

Notice that the `DataContext` for the data grid is not set - only the `ItemsSource`.

The change event for the text box should then look like:

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
  _viewSource.View.Refresh();
}
```

---

The performance problem is mainly a render/layout-problem caused by `"Auto"` setting for the grid row containing the data grid, so in the xaml for the control you must remove the `ScrollViewer` and define the grid as follows:

```
  <Grid Background="Transparent" FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=txtSearch}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Notice the second row definition:

```
<RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
```

Setting `Height="*"` instead of `"Auto"` is important because it will eliminate the need for the outer `ScrollViewer` and speed up the calculations of the dimensions of the data grid, when rendering (You may set it to a static value, but not `"Auto"`)

---

The data grid should then be defined as:

```
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Name="MainGrid"
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
              EnableRowVirtualization="True"
          Sorting="MainGrid_Sorting"
          SelectionChanged="MainGrid_SelectionChanged"
          MouseDoubleClick="MainGrid_MouseDoubleClick"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              AlternationCount="2"
          AlternatingRowBackground="DimGray"
          Margin="0,0,0,0">
```

Notice the missing `Binding` for `ItemsSource`.

With these changes everything should work smoothly and efficiently.

You may want to experiment with `EnableRowVirtualization="True/False"` to see which state is most smooth.

---

You should remove the column header style on every column because they are the same and then define it in the `UserControl.Resources` as:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF666666" />
  <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
</Style>
```